# How to make a program which will tell the user how many letters were in their surname or firstname

Tags: python

How to make a program which will tell the user how many letters were in their surname or first name. Here I have the code so maybe you have any adjustments to it just let me know. Thanks:)

[image]

Comment: put code as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: `print(len(firstname), len(surname))`

Comment: print "Length of the name: ", len(firstname) etc.

Comment: @furas thank you I'll try it out now:)

Comment: @furas I used your advice and now I'm currently trying to show the user how many letters are in their first name and surname. But heres the following code:

Comment: @furas btw there are no errors but it doesn't say the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @furas      print("You have",len(firstname),"letters in your firstname","and", len(surname)),"letters in your surname"

Comment: You have last `)` in wrong place

Comment: @furas unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @furas can you please send me the edited code

Comment: I can't send because you put screenshot - it is your job to put code as text.

Comment: How to I do though?

Comment: can you copy and paste it?

Comment: you can edit question and put code as text - and then others can use it to create solution. This is why we don't like screenshots.

Comment: in code from comment you have last `)` after `len(firstname)` and you have to move it at the end `print("You have", len(firstname), "letters in your firstname and", len(surname), "letters in your surname")`

Answer (score -2):

print( len( input("what is your name? ") ) )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, your code is in an image. I use a [screen reader](http://enwp.org/screen_reader) so can't see the image, but I can write an example program:

```
#Example 1, count all characters in the user's input
fn=input("What is your first name?")
ln=input("What is your surname?")
print("Your first name has " + str(len(fn)) + " characters, and your surname has " + str(len(ln)) + " characters.")

#Example 2, count *only* ASCII letters in user's input
import string
fn=input("What is your first name?")
ln=input("What is your surname?")
fncount=0
lncount=0
for i in fn:
    if i in string.ascii_letters:
        fncount+=1
for i in ln:
    if i in string.ascii_letters:
        lncount+=1
print("Your first name has " + str(fncount) + " letters, and your surname has " + str(lncount) + " letters.")
```